# Setting Up a Private LAN Network within Another Network on Linux

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, router, lan

I'm seeking guidance on setting up a private LAN network within the confines of another network, all on Linux, using open-source firewalls and software. Here's the scenario:

I have a desktop computer that I want to connect to the internet. I want the desktop also hosts a local server connected via Ethernet to other machines, e.g., Raspberry Pi, a laptop, etc., forming a private LAN.

I want the desktop to have access to both the internet and the private LAN, while restricting any other machines to only communicate within the LAN without internet access. Additionally, I want to ensure that other computers on the main network, which have internet access but are not part of my private LAN, cannot see or access the private LAN or any remote access to them from the internet.

Could you please provide guidance on achieving this setup using open-source firewalls and software on Linux (popOS on desktop)? Additionally, I'd appreciate any tutorials or resources you could point me towards for further information on this topic.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: It depends on what you have available, and how the devices are physically connected together. Can you edit your question and add a basic diagram? A simple example is to connect Internet > Router1 > Desktop > Router2 > private LAN. That will work by default (no extra firewalling required), but you need two network interfaces on the desktop and two routers. If you only have one central point like a router, it needs to support some kind of isolation between connected devices like a guest network or vlans.

Comment: I am pretty clueless when it comes to networking. I think I would prefer to have another router/switch(?) that deals with the private LAN on its own separate from the router connected to the internet.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the computer has enough network interfaces physically – install a second Ethernet port if needed (as a PCIe card). Configure the second network interface with some IP address (must be a different IP subnet than your main network), then connect it to an Ethernet switch for all your "private LAN" devices.

You'll probably want to install a DHCP server for convenience (dnsmasq, isc-dhcp-server, or similar). Configure it to issue IP addresses on the new interface.

Finally, set up firewall rules to block all network traffic from or to the new interface – a pair of plain 'DROP' rules in the iptables or nftables 'FORWARD' chain. (Not enough to just keep IP forwarding disabled system-wide, as things like Docker would often re-enable it.)